# Will JBoss App Server (v5.01) load any .ear file in the deploy directory?

Tags: deployment, jboss

Will the JBoss App Server load any .ear file it sees in the deploy directory?  We want to name our .ear file differently based on whether it's built from the trunk or a branch.  I don't have first-hand experience with this since our deployment is done by another team.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

yes it will deploy all EAR files from deploy folder.

Comment: Typically our .ear is named TCEQParis.ear.  I renamed it to TCEQParisBranch.ear and it won't load.  I'm getting a lot of these errors:  2014-07-01 13:34:50,267 ERROR [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve] (ajp-204.67.188.101-8009-1) Application error: Faces Servlet did not complete its transaction

Comment: Add exception stack trace here to see why it is failing.